# Group items inside a Javascript array

Tags: javascript

I have the following data structure, which I have tried to group the sections inside by their parent level.

```
  const arr = [
    {
      level: '1.1',
      name: 'group title 1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.1.1',
      name: 'group section 1.1.1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.1.2',
      name: 'group section 1.1.2',
    },
    {
      level: '1.1.3',
      name: 'group section 1.1.3',
    },
    {
      level: '1.2',
      name: 'group title 2',
    },
    {
      level: '1.2.1',
      name: 'group section 1.1.1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.3',
      name: 'group title 3',
    },
    {
      level: '1.3.1',
      name: 'group section 1.1.1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.3.2',
      name: 'group section 1.1.2',
    },
    {
      level: '1.4',
      name: 'group title 4',
    },
    {
      level: '1.4.1',
      name: 'group section 1.4.1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.4.2',
      name: 'group section 1.4.2',
    },
    {
      level: '1.4.3',
      name: 'group section 1.4.3',
    },
  ];
```

I have been trying to change the structure to the following object (group the sections). The object has the parent level's value as property and an array of the sections.

```
  const obj = {
    '1.1': [
      {
        level: '1.1.1',
        name: 'group section 1.1.1',
      },
      {
        level: '1.1.2',
        name: 'group section 1.1.2',
      },
      {
        level: '1.1.3',
        name: 'group section 1.1.3',
      },
    ],
    '1.2': [
      {
        level: '1.2',
        name: 'group title 2',
      },
      {
        level: '1.2.1',
        name: 'group section 1.1.1',
      },
    ],
    '1.3': [
      {
        level: '1.3',
        name: 'group title 3',
      },
      {
        level: '1.3.1',
        name: 'group section 1.1.1',
      },
      {
        level: '1.3.2',
        name: 'group section 1.1.2',
      },
    ],
    '1.4': [
      {
        level: '1.4.1',
        name: 'group section 1.4.1',
      },
      {
        level: '1.4.2',
        name: 'group section 1.4.2',
      },
      {
        level: '1.4.3',
        name: 'group section 1.4.3',
      },
    ],
  };
```

My attempts were not successful. I would appreciate any help on how to change the structure to the above.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Looks like people don't want my **completely** explained answer in the list of answers. I am deleting my answer right now. Let me know if you want the answer I posted along with explanation, output and snippet. `:)`

Comment: How many levels will there be? Could it happen that you get `10.1` or possibly `1.10` or even more than 2 digits? - On a side-note: Is it a business requirement to be able to group by parent levels? If so then the parent level data should be saved in the data store instead of being derived and sent down along with the data to you in the first place.

Comment: Why isn't `level: 1.1` or `level: 1.4` in your output? It's not clear if the heading values should be on the resulting array or not.

Comment: Furthermore are the levels always pre-grouped like yours or could you have `1.1.3` followed by level `1.4.2` followed by `1.1.1`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) can be used to construct `objects` from `arrays`.

[`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) can be used to detect patterns in `strings`.

[`/\d+\.\d+/`](https://regexr.com/3n970) matches the first occurrence of one or more `numbers` followed by one `full stop` followed by one or more `numbers`

```js
// Input.
const input = [{level: '1.1',name: 'group title 1',},{level: '1.1.1',name: 'group section 1.1.1',},{level: '1.1.2',name: 'group section 1.1.2',},{level: '1.1.3',name: 'group section 1.1.3',},{level: '1.2',name: 'group title 2',},{level: '1.2.1',name: 'group section 1.1.1',},{level: '1.3',name: 'group title 3',},{level: '1.3.1',name: 'group section 1.1.1',},{level: '1.3.2',name: 'group section 1.1.2',},{level: '1.4',name: 'group title 4',},{level: '1.4.1',name: 'group section 1.4.1',},{level: '1.4.2',name: 'group section 1.4.2',},{level: '1.4.3',name: 'group section 1.4.3',},]

// Group.
const group = (array) => array.reduce((o, x) => {
  const key = x.level.match(/\d+\.\d+/)
  if (o[key]) o[key].push(x)
  else o[key] = [x]
  return o
}, {})

// Output.
const output = group(input)

// Proof.
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, and following the DRY principle, a more elegant way would be to use Lodash that already has this function.

```
const group = arr =>_.groupBy(arr, x => x.level.match(/\d+\.\d+/));
```

> **_.groupBy** https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy
>
> Creates an object composed of keys generated from the results of
>   running each element of collection thru iteratee. The order of grouped
>   values is determined by the order they occur in collection. The
>   corresponding value of each key is an array of elements responsible
>   for generating the key.

But of course that is if you are allowed to use an external library.

Resulting snippet

```js
const arr = [
    {
      level: '1.1',
      name: 'group title 1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.1.1',
      name: 'group section 1.1.1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.1.2',
      name: 'group section 1.1.2',
    },
    {
      level: '1.1.3',
      name: 'group section 1.1.3',
    },
    {
      level: '1.2',
      name: 'group title 2',
    },
    {
      level: '1.2.1',
      name: 'group section 1.1.1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.3',
      name: 'group title 3',
    },
    {
      level: '1.3.1',
      name: 'group section 1.1.1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.3.2',
      name: 'group section 1.1.2',
    },
    {
      level: '1.4',
      name: 'group title 4',
    },
    {
      level: '1.4.1',
      name: 'group section 1.4.1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.4.2',
      name: 'group section 1.4.2',
    },
    {
      level: '1.4.3',
      name: 'group section 1.4.3',
    },
  ];

const group = arr =>_.groupBy(arr, x => x.level.match(/\d+\.\d+/));

const result = group(arr);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

In your question it wasn't clear if you need the headers as well (1.1, 1.2, etc), the above version includes them. But if you don't want them, you first need to erase them from the array:

```
arr.filter(x => !/^\d+\.\d+$/.test(x.level))
```

And all together

```
const group = arr => {
  const noheaders = arr.filter(x => !/^\d+\.\d+$/.test(x.level));
  return _.groupBy(noheaders, x => x.level.match(/\d+\.\d+/));
}
```

```js
const arr = [
    {
      level: '1.1',
      name: 'group title 1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.1.1',
      name: 'group section 1.1.1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.1.2',
      name: 'group section 1.1.2',
    },
    {
      level: '1.1.3',
      name: 'group section 1.1.3',
    },
    {
      level: '1.2',
      name: 'group title 2',
    },
    {
      level: '1.2.1',
      name: 'group section 1.1.1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.3',
      name: 'group title 3',
    },
    {
      level: '1.3.1',
      name: 'group section 1.1.1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.3.2',
      name: 'group section 1.1.2',
    },
    {
      level: '1.4',
      name: 'group title 4',
    },
    {
      level: '1.4.1',
      name: 'group section 1.4.1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.4.2',
      name: 'group section 1.4.2',
    },
    {
      level: '1.4.3',
      name: 'group section 1.4.3',
    },
  ];

const group = arr => {
  const noheaders = arr.filter(x => !/^\d+\.\d+$/.test(x.level));
  return _.groupBy(noheaders, x => x.level.match(/\d+\.\d+/));
}

const result = group(arr);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I appreciate the downvote, but at least leave some feedback on why you think I can improve my answer

Comment: For some reason, people seem to hate lodash around here.

Comment: lodash is the new jquery

Comment: yep, my theory is that  `reduce(mess)` or `getElementBySomeMess` instead of `_.groupBy` or `$(blah)` somehow helps people feel more "professional".

Answer (score 0):

```
  const obj = {};

  for(const {level, name} of array) {
    const key = level.split(".").slice(0, 2).join(".");
    if(obj[key]) {
      obj[key].push({ level, name });
    } else {
      obj[key] = [ { level, name } ];
    }
  }
```

To understand whats going on, the following pages might help:

[for ... of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

[object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

[Array#push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

This is a simplified version of the expected output. Please check the output in browser console, hence there is an issue with the snippet. Thank you.

```js
var parent = [];
  var child =[];
  var result =[];

const arr = [
    {
      level: '1.1',
      name: 'group title 1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.1.1',
      name: 'group section 1.1.1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.1.2',
      name: 'group section 1.1.2',
    },
    {
      level: '1.1.3',
      name: 'group section 1.1.3',
    },
    {
      level: '1.2',
      name: 'group title 2',
    },
    {
      level: '1.2.1',
      name: 'group section 1.1.1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.3',
      name: 'group title 3',
    },
    {
      level: '1.3.1',
      name: 'group section 1.1.1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.3.2',
      name: 'group section 1.1.2',
    },
    {
      level: '1.4',
      name: 'group title 4',
    },
    {
      level: '1.4.1',
      name: 'group section 1.4.1',
    },
    {
      level: '1.4.2',
      name: 'group section 1.4.2',
    },
    {
      level: '1.4.3',
      name: 'group section 1.4.3',
    },
  ];

  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  if(arr[i].level.length == 3){
 
  parent.push(arr[i]);
  }else{
  child.push(arr[i]);
  }
  }
  
  for(var j=0;j<parent.length;j++){
  result[parent[j].level]=[];
  for(var k=0;k<child.length;k++){
  if(parent[j].level.substring(0, 3)== child[k].level.substring(0, 3)){
   result[parent[j].level].push(child[k]); 
  }
  } 
  }
 console.log(result);
```